# Are there any advanced options of setting values of properties in jmeter properties file

Tags: jmeter, properties-file

I got test.properties file for my jmeter test. It contains some enviro property=value pairs and those work nicely.

But I would like to add something like this:

```
a1 = value
b1 = value

a2 = a1+b1
b2 = value

a3 = a2+b2
b3 = value
```

When I use "hardcoded" value, like 10 for a2 and 20 for a3, the properties are loaded and used correctly. But a1+b1 does not work as required. Is there any way how to assigned sum of two properties as a value of another property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.properties file is just textual [name-value pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribute%E2%80%93value_pair), it doesn't assume any evaluation logic.

- If you need to sum 2 properties you need to go for [__longSum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__longSum) like:

  ```
   ${__longSum(${__P(a1,)},${__P(b1,)},)}
  ```
- If you need to store the result into another JMeter property - use [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty)

  ```
   ${__setProperty(a2,${__longSum(${__P(a1,)},${__P(b1,)},)},)}
  ```

Demo:

[image]

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction)

Also as per [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter) user manual chapter you shouldn't be using *jmeter.properties* file itself for extra configuration, it should go either to *user.properties* or external .properties file

Comment: Looks like a right direction, Dimitri. So if I define property in one thread group, will it be accessible from other thread groups as well?

Comment: Yes, [properties are "global" for the whole JMeter/JVM instance](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html). Just make sure that the Thread Group which is defining this `a2` property and similar ones which are calculated is executed **before** the Thread Group(s) where the value is used, a good idea is using [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-setup-thread-group-jmeter-when-preparing-load-test) for this